# Pass data from website a to website b using java script to then use as a post query

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, curl

I have **website A** i need to pass info to **website B**.

**website A** a user is logged in, using the current session on **website A** i will collect **UserID** from the session and i want to post **UserID** and **UniID=3** to a data structure on **website B** that will store the data in variables that can be used in a post query from **website B**

I was thinking of using simple JavaScript like (on website A)

```
<div id="linkto"> <p>www.websiteb.com/&uniId=3 <P></div>

$('linkto').on('click',function(event){

UserId['UserId'] = $UserId 
$(post).(url'www.websiteb.com', data );

});
```

then collecting the **UserID** and **UniID** somehow and then using them as variables in a post query

My question is this the correct way of going about it, I basically need to collect **UserID** from one website and use it on another website

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/387194) you only need to add `$_GET['uniId']` and `$_SESSION['UserId']` to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look at it. im a bit lost on the best way to do this and where to start. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I may have solved it.

**Website A**

```
<script language="JavaScript">

JSarray = new Array();
JSarray[0] = "$UserId";
JSarray[1] = "$var2";

function send_value(){document.myform.secret.value = JSarray.toString();}
```

**Website B**

```
    <?php
$secret = $_POST['secret'];
$ar=explode(',',$secret);
print_r($ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set up the link like you have www.websiteb.com?&uniId=3. One you get to website B you covert uniId in a session and than redirect to the URL with out the uniId in the URL. This way you now have it as a session.

```html
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['unvId'] = $_GET['unvId'];

header('Location: http://websiteb.com');
```

Comment: Hey @Jeff this may be a better idea, so I would need to send with my javascrip, then in the post action send to  www.websiteb.com?&uniId=3 ? I understand your idea but am a bit lost on how to do this

Comment: I do not know how you are presenting the uniId on the page but it could be as easy as <a href="www.websiteb.com&uniId=<?php echo $unilId ?>" target="_blank">www.websiteb.com&uniId=<?php echo $unilId ?></a>.